# linux mint 18.2 Cinnamon 32-bit - sudo apt-get update shows apt-get not found error

Tags: linux-mint, apt

While running `sudo apt-get update`, command gives below error on linux mint 18.2 Cinnamon 32-bit:

```
/usr/bin/apt-get: 1: /usr/bin/apt-get: ELF: not found
/usr/bin/apt-get: 1: /usr/bin/apt-get: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Comment: Nope. apt-get repository may deleted bimistakenly by some command

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/q/1032626/436624

Comment: please do `more /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | cat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `apt-get` binary somehow got corrupted (“ELF” is part of the ELF signature but your kernel isn’t recognising it as such, so your shell is trying to run it as a script). You need to reinstall it:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/1.2.26/+build/14435269/+files/apt_1.2.26_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i apt_1.2.26_i386.deb
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen! This is very helpful for me. This saved my time.